# Unable to open DBF file

Tags: r

I am trying to convert multiple `*DBF` files to `.xlsx` using R. I am getting an error when:

```
files.to.read=list.files(pattern="DBF")

lapply(files.to.read, function(f) {
+     df = read.dbf(f)
+     write.xlsx(df, gsub("DBF", "xlsx", f), row.names=FALSE)
+ })
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you supply a `dput(head(df))`? What packages do I need to run this?